# JSON object not decoded

Tags: python, json, ubuntu-12.04, openstack, openstack-nova

I am using openstack and I get a response from **nova list** which is supposed to be in **json** but when I try:

```
  nova list | python -m json.tool
```

It returns:

```
  No JSON object could be decoded
```

I used http://jsonlint.com  to validate the response and It is valid. I used devstack to deploy openstack and I need to parse the response but it doesn't work. Any help? Thanks in advance. 
This is the Response:

```
{
"servers": [
    {
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "updated": "2014-01-17T08:08:30Z",
        "hostId": "bb9ca1b4e919712577cfb6d2ac5c6892e7faf4ee46a8a45322fc507f",
        "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host": "muawia-Inspiron-N4050",
        "addresses": {
            "public": [
                {
                    "OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr": "fa:16:3e:18:07:07",
                    "version": 4,
                    "addr": "192.168.1.194",
                    "OS-EXT-IPS:type": "fixed"
                }
            ]
        },
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "http://192.168.1.206:8774/v2/699eb4f6d2834bff80f28f40c0a08eb0/servers/202b6645-2ff9-4d2d-aacd-9a57566011e0",
                "rel": "self"
            },
            {
                "href": "http://192.168.1.206:8774/699eb4f6d2834bff80f28f40c0a08eb0/servers/202b6645-2ff9-4d2d-aacd-9a57566011e0",
                "rel": "bookmark"
            }
        ],
        "key_name": "newkey",
        "image": {
            "id": "e7c132bc-5d7b-4e77-b622-e146b69fdf9d",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.206:8774/699eb4f6d2834bff80f28f40c0a08eb0/images/e7c132bc-5d7b-4e77-b622-e146b69fdf9d",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ]
        },
        "OS-EXT-STS:task_state": null,
        "OS-EXT-STS:vm_state": "active",
        "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:instance_name": "instance-00000001",
        "OS-SRV-USG:launched_at": "2014-01-17T08:08:30.000000",
        "OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:hypervisor_hostname": "muawia-Inspiron-N4050",
        "flavor": {
            "id": "42",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://192.168.1.206:8774/699eb4f6d2834bff80f28f40c0a08eb0/flavors/42",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "202b6645-2ff9-4d2d-aacd-9a57566011e0",
        "security_groups": [
            {
                "name": "default"
            }
        ],
        "OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at": null,
        "OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone": "nova",
        "user_id": "75445728f6bc441b82ee057e55d49468",
        "name": "inst1",
        "created": "2014-01-17T08:06:24Z",
        "tenant_id": "699eb4f6d2834bff80f28f40c0a08eb0",
        "OS-DCF:diskConfig": "MANUAL",
        "os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached": [],
        "accessIPv4": "",
        "accessIPv6": "",
        "progress": 0,
        "OS-EXT-STS:power_state": 1,
        "config_drive": "",
        "metadata": {}
    }
]
}
```

Comment: What is this json.tool?

Comment: And when you pipe it to `cat`?

Comment: @RickyA decodes json.

Comment: nova list is not returning a json for me. How did you get a json??

Comment: @user3176971 well, apparently it doesn't. If you wrote it could you paste it in the question.

Comment: @Akilesh the response I posted is from nova list.

Comment: @RickyA `json.tool` is part of the Python standard library.

Comment: 1: can you do `nova list | cat`

Comment: 2: can you save above json in a textfile and do `cat filename | python -m json.tool`

Comment: @RickyA It works when I put it in a file `cat check | python -m json.tool`

Comment: Can any one tell me , why it doesn't work directly?

Comment: 3. ok, then the problem is in `nova list`. Can you do: `nova list >> check2` and then look if the contents of `check2` are exactly the same as your posted json

Comment: it it that you are using curl to get your json. I see that if you are accessing nova api through curl then the result is a json but the result also includes the response headers which are not json.